# UNIX domain socket read() always gets the wrong value

Tags: c++, sockets

I have to write a ["Sea Battle"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_%28game%29) game using UNIX domain sockets as an assignment. Server and client are on the same machine and it's just to learn about IPC.

Every ship has size one.

I ran into a problem which I can not solve and I hope you have an idea.

First I know that read(), write(), select(), ... has a return value and I check them. However I gonna leave them out that the code is better readable. And I also leave other unnecessary code out.

The server and the client are pretty much the same except the connection (which is not the problem) and they are in the opposite state, which is checked with turn==0 and turn!=0. Again I just write one.

**So my Problem: In the else the read function is nonblocking because of the console input in the if. I tried to solve that with select, but I always get wrong input. In the first move it always reads (0,0) in. In the enemy turn it uses the data from the last input.**

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    if(argv[1]==NULL){
        std::cout << "no socket path" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    Playfield field(5);

    fd_set rfds;
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);


    int turn = 0;
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_un address;
    int cordinate[2];
    int status[1];
    int gameInfo[1];

    if((sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM,0)) < 0){
        std::cerr << "error creating socket" << std::endl;
    }

    address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(address.sun_path, argv[1]);

    std::cout << "trying to connect..." << std::endl;

    if(connect(sock,(struct sockaddr*) &address, sizeof(address)) == 0){
        std::cout << "conected" << std::endl;

    int inputHeight;
    char inputLengthChar;
    bool noWinnerFound=true;
    FD_SET(sock, &rfds);

    while(noWinnerFound){

        read(sock, gameInfo, 1);
        if(gameInfo[0]<=0){
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout << "you have won. congratulation!" << std::endl;
            noWinnerFound=false;
            break;
        }
        gameInfo[0] = field.getRemainingShips();
        write(sock, gameInfo, 1);

        if(field.getRemainingShips()<=0){
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout << "you have lost." << std::endl;
            noWinnerFound=false;
            break;
        }

        if(turn%2!=0){
            std::cout << "your turn: " << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl;
            field.print();
            std::cout << "enter which field you want to attack" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> inputHeight >> inputLengthChar;
            if(inputHeight>field.getHeight() || inputHeight<0 ||((int)(inputLengthChar-65))>=field.getLength() || (int)inputLengthChar-65<0){
                std::cin.setstate(std::cin.failbit);
            }
            else if(field.getEnemyField(inputHeight-1,((int)(inputLengthChar-65))!=field.EMPTY_FIELD)){
                std::cout << "you already attacked that field" << std::endl;
                std::cin.setstate(std::cin.failbit);
            }
            while(std::cin.fail()){
                std::cout << "Please enter: number character" << std::endl;
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                std::cin >> inputHeight >> inputLengthChar;
                if(inputHeight>field.getHeight() || ((int)inputLengthChar)-65>=field.getLength()){
                    std::cin.setstate(std::cin.failbit);
                }
                else if(field.getEnemyField(inputHeight-1,((int)(inputLengthChar-65))!=field.EMPTY_FIELD)){
                    std::cout << "you already attacked that field" << std::endl;
                    std::cin.setstate(std::cin.failbit);
                }
            }

            cordinate[0] = inputHeight-1;
            cordinate[1] = ((int)(inputLengthChar-65));
            if(write(sock, cordinate, 2) == -1)
                std::cerr << "error writing" << std::endl;
            //select(sock2, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &stop);
            int n = select(sock+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            if(n == -1){
                std::cerr << "error select" << std::endl;
            } else{
                if(FD_ISSET(sock, &rfds)){
                    if(read(sock, status, 1) == -1)
                        std::cerr << "error reading" << std::endl;
                    if(status[0]==field.SHIP){
                        field.setEnemyField(cordinate[0], cordinate[1], field.SHIP);
                        std::cout << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "you hit a ship" << std::endl;
                    }

                    else{
                        field.setEnemyField(cordinate[0], cordinate[1], field.ATTACKED);
                    }
                }
            }

            field.print();
            ++turn;

        }

        else{
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout << "enemy turn please wait" << std::endl;
            int n = select(sock+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            if(n == -1){
                std::cerr << "error select" << std::endl;
            } else{
                if(FD_ISSET(sock, &rfds)){
                    if(read(sock, cordinate, 2) <= 0)
                        std::cerr << "error reading" << std::endl;
                    status[0] = field.getField(cordinate[0], cordinate[1]);
                    write(sock, status, 1);
                    if(status[0]==field.SHIP){
                        field.decreaseRemainingShips();
                    }
                    else if(status[0]==field.EMPTY_FIELD){
                        field.setField(cordinate[0], cordinate[1], field.ATTACKED);
                    }
                }
            }
            ++turn;
        }
    }
}
else{
    std::cout << "no server found" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}

close(sock);

return 0;
```

}

Here an example:

Let's assume the ships are set like this:  (X stand for ship, O stands for attack which was not a ship)

```
   server:         client:
  A B C D E       A B C D E
1 X             1 X
2 X             2   X
3 X             3     X
4 X             4       X
5 X             5         X
```

the game starts you see a white board which represents the enemy board and the server attacks field (1,B) the output is:

```
   server:         client:
  A B C D E       A B C D E
1   X           1 
2               2   
3               3     
4               4       
5               5
```

which is obviously wrong but it uses the value of field (1,A) in the enemy turn it uses the value from the server input field. Let's say client attacks (1,A) which would hit a ship, but since the last attack did not hit a ship the output is:

```
   server:         client:
  A B C D E       A B C D E
1   X           1 O
2               2   
3               3     
4               4       
5               5
```

I hope I could make it clear. If anybody could help I would appreciate it.

Comment: You can't leave out the return value of read. Correctness depends on it. In the problematic line you're ignoring it which is probably part of the trouble you have. What if it returned 1 although you expected 2 bytes to be read?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. As I mentioned at the start of the topic I check them I just leave them here out that it is better readable here.

Comment: I have troubling looking for true bugs in the presence of obvious "false" bugs in the code sample. Please just post the full version that is, in your mind, 100% correct. Many people are misusing `read` (because it is hard to use correctly) and I can't tell from this code whether your use is correct. How could I ever find your problem under these circumstances? You are even saying that the problem is in this very line! How can I review a line of code that you don't show?

Comment: Changed it. I didn't show because i thought it would be easier for others to read. And thought that this is not the problem. I just copied my client in. Anyway I appreciate any help and thank you for your time.

Comment: `read(sock, cordinate, 2) <= 0` should be `< 2` because read can read partial data (one byte in this case). This is not an error case. You probably need a read loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a partially uninitialized variable. `gameInfo` is an int (usually four bytes), but you read only 1 byte into it. Furthermore, since you actually use it as an int elsewhere, endianness issues come into play.

You're lucky here since you're likely on a little endian platform, but you still can't make `gameInfo` negative by reading a value if it wasn't before and the other way around, can't make it positive if it was negative before.

Comment: Now that you mention it, it hit me like a truck. I have no idea why I set this to only 1 byte and looking at the other reads and writes I did similar mistakes. Thank you

Comment: I corrected all these faults and it works now as intended. Thank you two for the help.